# Synology DS420+, mariadb permission denied in /volume1/logs/mysql

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb, synology

I would like to put the MariaDB logs in an easily accessible place (without having to go through the ssh), but I couldn't do it.
My current configuration is as follows:

```
[mysqld]
general_log
general_log_file=/volume1/logs/mysql/general.log
# log_error=/volume1/logs/mysql/error.log # while waiting for the general logs to work
```

I did `chown -R mysql:mysql /volume1/logs/mysql`

> drwxrwxrwx+ 1 mysql mysql 0 Jun 8 00:12 mysql

Then if you have a way to put the logs in the Synology log center, I take it!

Comment: ok, I just understood that there is an extended permission system (the "+" after standard permissions), I'll look into it in detail.

https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/tutorial/How_to_manage_ACL_settings_on_your_Synology_NAS

Comment: Great that you were able to solve your issue, but please post your solution as an answer instead of editing it into your post. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question and accept it, otherwise the question will stay forever in the system as unsolved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had to put "Traverse folders/Execute files" on the shared folder and make the children inherit it.

ACL permissions > Read > Traverse folders/Execute files
help: https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_share_privilege?version=7#b_25